# how to find the longest same number in R

Tags: r

for example I have data like this

```
x<-c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1)
```

I want find the longest sequence of "1" by considering the start and end position, in this case should be (3,6)

How to do this in R

thanks all

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach that uses `seqle` from the "cgwtools" package:

```
library(cgwtools)
y <- seqle(which(x == 1))
z <- which.max(y$lengths)
y$values[z] + (sequence(y$lengths[z]) - 1)
# [1] 3 4 5 6
```

You can use `range` if you just wanted the "3" and "6".

`seqle` "extends `rle` to find and encode linear sequences".

---

Here's the answer as a function:

```
longSeq <- function(invec, range = TRUE) {
  require(cgwtools)
  y <- seqle(which(invec == 1))
  z <- which.max(y$lengths)
  out <- y$values[z] + (sequence(y$lengths[z]) - 1)
  if (isTRUE(range)) range(out) else out
}
```

Usage would be:

```
x <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
longSeq(x)
# [1] 3 6
longSeq(x, range = FALSE)
# [1] 3 4 5 6
```

And, with KFB's example input:

```
y <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
longSeq(y)
# [1]  9 11
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with base R too using `rle` and `inverse.rle` combination

**Creating the funciton**

```
longSeq2 <- function(x, range = TRUE){
  temp <- rle(x == 1)
  temp$values <- temp$lengths == max(temp$lengths[temp$values == TRUE]) 
  temp <- which(inverse.rle(temp))
  if (isTRUE(range)) range(temp) else temp
}
```

**Testing**

```
x <- c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1)
longSeq2(x)
## [1] 3 6
longSeq2(x, range = FALSE)
## [1] 3 4 5 6

y <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
longSeq2(y)
## [1] 9 11
longSeq2(y, range = FALSE)
## [1] 9 10 11
```